# Click any image opens popup and change image url like

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually I need to replace image url when i click image then open a popup window with input field and I put url and and save it but using this method.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eDMmy/9/

```js
//Set up the dialog box
$("#myDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen  : false,
    modal     : true,
    title     : "A Dialog Box",
    buttons   : {
              'OK' : function() {
                  var textValue = $('#myTextBox').val();
                  var image1 = document.getElementById("image1");
                  image1.src=textValue;
                  
              },
              'Close' : function() {
                  alert('The Close button was clicked');
                  $(this).dialog('close');
              }
                }
});
```

```css
.img {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
```

```html
<img class='img' src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full5/Nature/Animals/animals-89a.jpg" onclick="ChangeUrl()" id="image1">
    
<div id="myDialog">
    change url 
    <input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
</div>
   <script>
       function ChangeUrl(){ 
     $("#myDialog").dialog("open");

    var image1 = document.getElementById("image1");
            $("#myTextBox").val(image1.src);
    image1.src= url;
       }</script>
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I need to multiple Image that click image and change this image not another Image. EX: I add 3 image and when I click 2 no image and change only 2 no image same as when I click 1 no image that change only 1 no image and when click 3 no image that change only 3 no image that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the text field instead of reading from it, do this instead:

```
var image1 = document.getElementById("image1");
var url = $("#myTextBox").val();
image1.src= url;
```

Comment: Thanks "Nayish" for your answer, But 
 
I need to multiple Image that click image and change this image not another Image. EX: I add 3 image and when I click 2 no image and change only 2 no image same as when I click 1 no image that change only 1 no image and when click 3 no image that change only 3 no image that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target only that image you clicked. `.data()` is important in this case to be able to pass the arguments. Check this solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/eDMmy/687/

```js
//Set up the dialog box
$("#myDialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  title: "A Dialog Box",
  buttons: {
    'OK': function() {
      var img_to_update = $(this).data('link');
      var textValue = $('#myTextBox').val();
      document.getElementById(img_to_update).src = textValue;
    },
    'Close': function() {
      //alert('The Close button was clicked');
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<img class='img' src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full5/Nature/Animals/animals-89a.jpg" onclick="ChangeUrl(this.id)" id="image1">
<img class='img' src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg" onclick="ChangeUrl(this.id)" id="image2">
<img class='img' src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png" onclick="ChangeUrl(this.id)" id="image3">

<div id="myDialog">
  change url
  <input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
</div>
<script>
  function ChangeUrl(x) {
    //$("#myDialog").dialog("open");
    $("#myDialog")
      .data('link', x)
      .dialog('open');
    var url = document.getElementById(x).src;
    $('#myTextBox').val(url);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer "tech2017" Actually I am use this code in my html page builder so I need to avoided image id and onclick="ChangeUrl(this.id)" on image tag or delete image id and onclick="ChangeUrl(this.id)"  after change image url for clean code. Can you help me.

Comment: Wow!! Awesome!! Thank you so much for your great and perfect  answer "tech2017" Actually I need this. Thank you

Comment: Hi tech2017, How can I use this code http://jsfiddle.net/eDMmy/688/ for iframe url change example youtube google map etc please help me

Comment: iframe url can be changed like this: `var $iframe = $('#' + iframeName);   $iframe.attr('src',newurl);`

Comment: Thanks tech2017, But  I don't understand where put this code please example if possible

Comment: No Actually I need to same as image url change with popup and input box then put the url then change url like http://jsfiddle.net/eDMmy/688/ just deference image to video or map Iframe  that's it

Comment: it will be better if you try and share your fiddle if it does not work.